# How to loop the program after an exception is thrown

Tags: java, exception

I have the following code that might throw exceptions:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

class Test {
    public static void main (String [] args) {
        try {
            Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);
            int n1, n2;
            System.out.print("Type an int: ");
            n1 = keyboard.nextInt();
            System.out.print("Type another int: ");
            n2 = keyboard.nextInt();
            int r = n1/n2;
        }
        catch (ArithmeticException e) {
            System.out.println("Divide by 0");


        }
        catch (InputMismatchException e) {
            System.out.println("Wrong entry");
        }
    }
}
```

After an exception is thrown. I want the program to go back to asking the user to enter a new int again instead of exiting.

Comment: You want to put a loop around that.

Comment: Have you learned about [repetition statements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html) yet?

Comment: You you don't restart a program; you simply stop it from terminating (with an infinite loop).

Comment: Yes but I want it to loop only if it catches an exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap your code with a `while (true)` and add a `break` at the end of the `try` block, so that it will be reached only if no exceptions are thrown.

e.g.

```
while (true) {

    try {

        // your code goes here ....

        break;    // this will only be reached if no exceptions thrown
    }
    catch (...) { 

    }
};  // close the while loop

// this will be reached after the break only, i.e. no exceptions
```

Answer (score 1):

```
while (true) {

    try {

        // your code

        break;
    }
    catch (Exception e) { 

    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use an [infinite loop](https://www.baeldung.com/infinite-loops-java). You can exit it using a [`break`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html) statement when you are ready.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        while (true) {
            try {
                @SuppressWarnings("resource")
                Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
                int n1, n2;
                System.out.print("Type an int: ");
                n1 = keyboard.nextInt();
                System.out.print("Type another int: ");
                n2 = keyboard.nextInt();
                int r = n1 / n2;
                //Do whatever... use 'break' to exit the loop when you are done
            } catch (ArithmeticException e) {
                System.out.println("Divide by 0");

            } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
                System.out.println("Wrong entry");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Either a `break` or a boolean flag combined with `while (myFlag) ...`

Answer (score 0):

I don't like the "while (true) with a break" idiom. I find it clearer in this case -- I rarely have rules that apply in all cases -- to introduce an auxiliary variable that controls looping.

```
boolean repeat;
do {
    repeat = false;
    try {  
        ...stuff...
    }
    catch (SomeException ex) {
        ... error stuff...
        repeat = true;
    }
while (repeat);
```

This is (a) makes the loop termination clearer than arbitrary jumps ('break') out of the loop, and (b) makes it trivial when you find you have other reasons to re-do the loop body.